# Hmisc describe short version

Tags: r

Is there a way to only show the first 2 lines of output from the `describe` command in `Hmisc`?

For data safety reasons I can only really show `n`, `missing`, `unique` and `mean` in my output and possibly a histogram.

This means that I would have to hide the output for `lowest`, `highest` as well as frequencies and percentiles.

Is this possible? If not I'll probably have to calculate the values myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
library(Hmisc)

res <- describe(rnorm(400))

#Look at the structure.
str(res)
#It's a list! You can change the objects in it.

res$counts <- res$counts[1:4]
res$values <- NULL

print(res)
#rnorm(400) 
#      n missing  unique    Mean 
#    400       0     400 0.05392
```

Comment: What if it is a data frame that should be `describe`d, e.g. `res <- describe(iris)`? I suppose that requires a line or two extra?

Comment: @Henrik Looking at the output of `str(res)` should help you finding the list entries you want to change. No extra line required, simply do, e.g., `res$Sepal.Length$values <- NULL`. If you have many columns you might want to employ `lapply`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I just thought of something `lapply`-ish, instead of entering each variable name, if @Joanne have a dataframe with many variables. That may make your nice answer more general. I think. Cheers!

Comment: Sure, but I don't feel like adding that, because it was not asked for specifically and would just reiterate basic operations on nested lists which have been demonstrated on SO numerous times.

Comment: I fully understand that. On a large df I believe a non-Hmisc way would be easier and far more transparent anyway. Thanks for taking your time.